# c# image rotations

Tags: c#

I need some help with an issue that is truly giving me a headache. It's an application that allows the user to load an image file and then rotate the image clockwise or counterclockwise 90 degrees. The code works fine, however if the user rotates the image clockwise and then decides to rotate it back to the initial position via counterclockwise the image is not where it should be. I'm not sure what I am missing as I am very new to c#. Below is the code I am using for the clockwise rotation.

```
private int cW = 0;
private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    rotateTransform.CenterX = image1.ActualWidth / 2.0;
    rotateTransform.CenterY = image1.ActualHeight / 2.0;
    cW += 90;

    rotateTransform.Angle = cW;

    TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    transformGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform);

    image1.RenderTransform = transformGroup; 
}
```

I have completely changed the code using if/else statements. The following gives me the result I was looking for.

```
RotateTransform cwRotateTransform;
private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cwRotateTransform == null)
    {
        cwRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    }

    image1.LayoutTransform = cwRotateTransform;

    if (cwRotateTransform.Angle == 360)
        cwRotateTransform.Angle = 0;

    else cwRotateTransform.Angle += 90;
}
```

For counter-clockwise simply change "90" to "-90" for else `cwRotateTransform.Angle`.

Comment: `...the image is not where it should be.` What does this mean? Where is the image?

Comment: Where does the image need to be? Thank you for the help

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Can you post the code for the counterclockwise rotation?

Comment: for the counterclockwise I am using the same code except i am using 270 degrees in place of the 90, if that makes sense?

Comment: @user2029074 Wy don't you just use rotateflip, much easier to implement, just need to put the image in a bitmap.

Comment: @user2029074: can you post your solution as answer and mark it as such?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me using a picturebox and a bitmap which uses rotateflip:

```
Bitmap bitmapPicturebox1;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\Wallpaper.jpg";
}
private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bitmapPicturebox1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    bitmapPicturebox1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmapPicturebox1;
}  

private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bitmapPicturebox1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    bitmapPicturebox1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmapPicturebox1;
}
```

Comment: I have no problem getting this code to work with windows forms. Shouldn't it work with WPF(which is what I am working with) as well?

Comment: @user2029074 Just a second trying now.

Comment: This site should help me out with my issue. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/image-transformation-in-wpf/

Comment: @user2029074 was trying that but didn't show anything so tried something else still no result. If it works I'll edit the post.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Please let me know if you have any luck!